# catch when data content is modified in customContrl

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I have a question that I can't find an answer (and I am sure it is due to my limitation :) .

I have a custom control which contains a Grid and its items sources is already filled let's say using a timer. So when I use that custom control in my application (in a wpf) after each 10 seconds, the grid will have some data.

What I want to know, is there a way to catch when the grid content is modified and this from my application, so I will be able to save the content into a file?

I tried to override the Event OnTargetModied but did not succed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an event if you already know where in your code that you are updating your items sources. In your timer, after each 10 seconds, after you fill the items sources, also call a method to save the content to a file.

Like this:

```
// The timer runs every 10 seconds, and it calls this method every time
void TimerCallback()
{
  // 1. Update the items sources data here

  // 2. Save the content into a file here
}
```

Comment: let say that I can't access the code of the customControl. I want to access th content from my code .

Comment: It would be helpful to the helpers if you posted some code.  Your description of the problem is vague.  For example, we don't see HOW you are updating your items sources. Is this a data binding? Or are you doing it directly from code-behind?